# Java Optional "while not null" equivalent

Tags: java, option-type

Let us assume we start out with this code

```
while ((element = getNextElement()) != null) {
   // do something
}
```

and want to rewrite it so that getNextElement() returns an `Optional` as opposed to something that might be `null`.

What would be the preferred way to do that? Something like

```
while ((element = getNextElement()) && element.isPresent()) {

}
```

... or is there a better way?

There is also

```
for (Optional<ElementType> element = getNextElement(); element.isPresent(); element = getNextElement()) {
   // do something
}
```

Are there other/better options (pun intended, I suppose) for this?

Comment: Why not `getNextElement().isPresent()`?

Comment: the while loop with "if(!element.isPresent()) break;" is readable and succint enough, in my opinion

Comment: What that original piece of code actually does is it supposed to have a method like `Iterable<ElementType> getElements()`. Or `Iterator<ElementType>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Stream.generate(this::getNextElement) ...
```

The above would generate a `Stream<Optional<Element>>`. I believe that in java 9 there is a `flatMap` possibility.

For now:

```
Stream.generate(this::getNextElement)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .forEach(...);
```

Comment: Yes, Java9 has `Optional::stream`, produces a `0-1` element stream.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot for including the second code snippet there, too, very helpful. :)

Comment: Even though my question was marked as a duplicate, I liked your answer better.

Comment: Wouldn't this generate an infinte loop ?

Comment: @NicolásVera the question's title is misleading; asked was looping over Optional elements. Not looping while an optional boolean or such. Since java 9 one can do without isPresent + get.